# Non-recursive merge sort with two nested loops - how?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

First question here, and yes this is a homework question. We are tasked with performing merge sort on an array (which I am familiar with), but in a way I am unsure of how to do. Usually I would have a separate merge and merge sort function, and use the two. However, it sounds like he wants everything in one method? I was just hoping maybe someone could help clear things up for me, or put them into terms I can better understand.

From the assignment:

> you will need to implement a non-recursive version of merge-sort
>   algorithm. Arrange two nested loops to accomplish this task. The outer
>   loop should provide the size of segments for merging. The inner loop
>   should take care of selecting positions of segments. The inner loop
>   should start at the left edge and move your segments to the right.
>   Arrange appropriate values of variables left, middle, right, so that
>   sorting is accomplished just by iterating the call
>   merge(a,left,middle,right).

I hate to be so vague, but I really don't understand any of what he's saying. First, what is meant by "outer loop should provide the size of segments"? How does a loop *provide* anything? What about the next sentence - what does he mean by segments? The data?

I'm not asking for code, but any psuedocode would be really helpful.

If anyone could try and decipher what he means, I'd appreciate it. I've already emailed him about it, but it's been a few hours and I've yet to hear back.

Thank you!

Comment: I think by "provides" he means that there will be code at the top of the outer loop that calculates the segment size(s) and stores it in a local variable, which then can be accessed by the inner loop.  "segments" probably refers to sub-sections of the array.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It's not so difficult. Consider the recursive merge:

```
       +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
       | | | | | | | | |
       +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
            /     \               split
    +-+-+-+-+     +-+-+-+-+
    | | | | |     | | | | |
    +-+-+-+-+     +-+-+-+-+
      /   \         /  \          split
  +-+-+  +-+-+  +-+-+  +-+-+
  | | |  | | |  | | |  | | |
  +-+-+  +-+-+  +-+-+  +-+-+
  / \     / \     / \     / \     split
+-+ +-+ +-+ +-+ +-+ +-+ +-+ +-+
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
+-+ +-+ +-+ +-+ +-+ +-+ +-+ +-+
  \ /     \ /     \ /     \ /     merge
  +-+-+  +-+-+  +-+-+  +-+-+
  | | |  | | |  | | |  | | |
  +-+-+  +-+-+  +-+-+  +-+-+
      \   /         \  /          merge
    +-+-+-+-+     +-+-+-+-+
    | | | | |     | | | | |
    +-+-+-+-+     +-+-+-+-+
            \     /               merge
       +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
       | | | | | | | | |
       +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

If you notice, when you split, you don't really do anything. You just tell the recursive function to partially sort the array. Sorting the array consists of first sorting both halves and then merging it. So basically, what you have is this:

```
+-+ +-+ +-+ +-+ +-+ +-+ +-+ +-+
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
+-+ +-+ +-+ +-+ +-+ +-+ +-+ +-+
  \ /     \ /     \ /     \ /     merge
  +-+-+  +-+-+  +-+-+  +-+-+
  | | |  | | |  | | |  | | |
  +-+-+  +-+-+  +-+-+  +-+-+
      \   /         \  /          merge
    +-+-+-+-+     +-+-+-+-+
    | | | | |     | | | | |
    +-+-+-+-+     +-+-+-+-+
            \     /               merge
       +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
       | | | | | | | | |
       +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

Now from here it should be obvious. You first merge elements of the array 2 by 2, then 4 by 4, then 8 by 8 etc. That is the outer `for` gives you 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, ... (which is what it calls *size of the segment* because the `i` of the loop contains that number) and the inner `for` (say with iterator `j`) goes over the array, `i` by `i` merging `array[j...j+i/2-1]` with `array[j+i/2..j+i-1]`.

I wouldn't write the code since this is homework.

**Edit:** a picture of how the inner `for` works

Imagine if `i` is 4, so you are at this stage:

```
  +-+-+  +-+-+  +-+-+  +-+-+
  | | |  | | |  | | |  | | |
  +-+-+  +-+-+  +-+-+  +-+-+
      \   /         \  /          merge
    +-+-+-+-+     +-+-+-+-+
    | | | | |     | | | | |
    +-+-+-+-+     +-+-+-+-+
```

you will have a `for` that once gives you `0`(which is `0*i`) as `j` and then `4` (which is `1*i`) as `j`. (if `i` was 2, you would have `j` going like 0, 2, 4, 6)

Now, once you need to merge `array[0..1]` with `array[2..3]` (which is formulated by `array[j..j+i/2-1]` and `array[j+i/2..j+i-1]` with `j = 0`) and then `array[4..5]` with `array[6..7]` (which is formulated by the same formulas `array[j...j+i/2-1]` and `array[j+i/2..j+i-1]` because now `j = 4`) That is:

```
i = 4:
       +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
       | | | | | | | | |
       +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
        ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
        | | | | | | | |
       / / / /   \ \ \ \
     (j  =  0)   (j  =  4)
      | | | |     | | | |
      j | | |     j | | |
      | | | j+i-1 | | | j+i-1
      | | j+i/2   | | j+i/2
      | j+i/2-1   | j+i/2-1
      | | | |     | | | |
      | | | |     | | | |
      \ / \ /     \ / \ /
       v   v       v   v
       merge       merge
```

Hope this is clear at least a little.

---

**Side help:** Just a hint if you don't really know how `for` works:

```
for (statement1; condition; statement2)
{
    // processing
}
```

is like writing

```
statement1;
while (condition)
{
    // processing
    statement2;
}
```

So, if you always wrote

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
```

it meant starting from 0, while `i` is smaller than 10, do something with `i` and then increment it. Now if you want `i` to change differently, you just change `statement2` such as:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 1024; i *= 2)
```

(Try to understand how that final `for` works based on its equivalent `while` that I wrote you)

Comment: @GWW Change the `+`s with glittering stars and any girl you want is yours :D

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm still a little confused though. This is kind of how I'm translating what you said:
`for (int i=1; i < ??/*when should this stop?*/; i*=2_{

 for (int j=0; j < sizeofArray; j++){

  merge //confused here as well - what 2 arrays am I merging?
 }
}`

Sorry the comment code is so ugly. Is there a way I can fix that?

Comment: Well, think about it, what does `i` show? The size of the segment that has to be divided in half and merged. What is the biggest segment that needs to be divided in half and merged?

Comment: About `j`, `j` is supposed to show the beginning of a section with length `i`. What are the beginnings of sections with length `i`? They are `0`, `i`, `2*i`, `3*i`, `4*i` etc. So `j` doesn't go 1 by 1, it goes `i` by `i`.

Comment: For i, I'm thinking the biggest segment that needs to be divided in half and merged is the original array. So if n is the size of the original array, stop at i = n?

Comment: exactly. Note that for simplification, I am assuming the size of the array is a power of two. If it is not, then there would be minor adjustments.

Comment: @iaacp, did this answer your question? Do you need more help?

Comment: @Shahbaz Phd guys are very awesome, very nice drawing. Do you know about [acsii-flow](http://www.asciiflow.com/#Draw) ?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, it looks nice. No diagonal lines though!

Comment: @Shahbaz yes no diagonal, and [John](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1420197/john) trying to extend it to draw circles also.

Answer (score 2):

#### Here's my lazy, iterative/bottom-up merge-sort implementation that uses `std::merge`:

```
template<class InIt, class OutIt>
OutIt mergesort(InIt begin, InIt const end, OutIt o /* auxiliary buffer */)
{
    ptrdiff_t j;
    for (j = 0; begin != end; ++begin, ++j)
    {
        for (ptrdiff_t n = 1; n <= j && j % (n * 2) == 0; n *= 2)
        {
            o = std::merge(o - n * 2, o - n, o - n, o, begin - n * 2);
            o = std::swap_ranges(begin - n * 2, begin, o - n * 2);
        }
        *o = *begin;
        ++o;
    }
    --j;
    for (ptrdiff_t m = 1, n = 1; n <= j; n *= 2)
    {
        if (j & n)
        {
            o = std::merge(o - (m + n), o - m, o - m, o, o - (m + n));
            o = std::swap_ranges(begin - (m + n), begin, o - (m + n));
            m += n;
        }
    }
    return o;
}
```

#### Here's an in-place version that uses `std::inplace_merge`:

```
template<class InIt>
InIt inplace_mergesort(InIt begin, InIt const end)
{
    ptrdiff_t j;
    for (j = 0; begin != end; ++begin, ++j)
    {
        for (ptrdiff_t n = 1; n <= j && j % (n * 2) == 0; n *= 2)
        { std::inplace_merge(begin - n * 2, begin - n, begin); }
    }
    --j;
    for (ptrdiff_t m = 1, n = 1; n <= j; n *= 2)
    {
        if (j & n)
        {
            std::inplace_merge(begin - (m + n), begin - m, begin);
            m += n;
        }
    }
    return begin;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is C# version of bottom-up-mergesort (for some more details you may refer to my blog @ http://dream-e-r.blogspot.com/2014/07/mergesort-arrays-and-lists.html)

```
void BottomUpMergesort(int[] a)
        {
            int[] temp = new int[a.Length];
            for (int runWidth = 1; runWidth < a.Length; runWidth = 2 * runWidth)
            {
                for (int eachRunStart = 0; eachRunStart < a.Length; 
                    eachRunStart = eachRunStart + 2 * runWidth)
                {
                    int start = eachRunStart;
                    int mid = eachRunStart + (runWidth - 1);
                    if(mid >= a.Length)
                    {
                        mid = a.Length - 1;
                    }
                    int end = eachRunStart + ((2 * runWidth) - 1);
                    if(end >= a.Length)
                    {
                        end = a.Length - 1;
                    }

                    this.Merge(a, start, mid, end, temp);
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
                {
                    a[i] = temp[i];
                }
            }
```

**And merge is defined as:**

```
void Merge(int[] a, int start, int mid, int end, int[] temp)
        {
            int i = start, j = mid+1, k = start;
            while((i<=mid) && (j<=end))
            {
                if(a[i] <= a[j])
                {
                    temp[k] = a[i];
                    i++;
                }
                else
                {
                    temp[k] = a[j];
                    j++;
                }
                k++;
            }
            while(i<=mid)
            {
                temp[k] = a[i];
                i++;
                k++;
            }
            while (j <= end)
            {
                temp[k] = a[j];
                j++;
                k++;
            }
            Assert.IsTrue(k == end+1);
            Assert.IsTrue(i == mid+1);
            Assert.IsTrue(j == end+1);
        }

        }
```

**Just for reference here is the TopDownMergesort:**

```
void TopDownMergesort(int[] a, int[] temp, int start, int end)
        {
            if(start==end)
            {
                //run size of '1'
                return;
            }
            int mid = (start + end) / 2;
            this.TopDownMergesort(a, temp, start, mid);
            this.TopDownMergesort(a, temp, mid + 1, end);
            this.Merge(a, start, mid, end, temp);
            for(int i = start;i<=end;i++)
            {
                a[i] = temp[i];
            }
        }
```

**UnitTests**

```
[TestMethod]
        public void BottomUpMergesortTests()
        {
            int[] a = { 13, 4, 1, 3, 8, 11, 9, 10 };
            this.BottomUpMergesort(a);
            int[] b = { 1, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13 };
            Assert.IsTrue(a.Length == b.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
            {
                Assert.IsTrue(a[i] == b[i]);
            }
            List<int> l = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 10; i >= 1; i--)
            {
                l.Add(i);
            }
            var la = l.ToArray();
            this.BottomUpMergesort(la);
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                Assert.IsTrue(la[i - 1] == i);
            }
            l.Clear();
            for (int i = 16; i >= 1; i--)
            {
                l.Add(i);
            }
            la = l.ToArray();
            this.BottomUpMergesort(la);
            for (int i = 1; i <= l.Count; i++)
            {
                Assert.IsTrue(la[i - 1] == i);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Java Implementation

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void iterativeMergeSort(T[] seed) {

    for (int i = 1; i <seed.length; i=i+i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < seed.length - i; j = j + i+i)
        {
            inPlaceMerge(seed, j, j + i-1, Math.min(j+i + i -1, seed.length -1));
        }
    }       
}
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>>  void inPlaceMerge(T[] collection, int low, int mid, int high) {
    int left = low;
    int right = mid + 1;

    if(collection[mid].equals(collection[right])) {
        return ;//Skip the merge if required
    }
    while (left <= mid && right <= high) {          
        // Select from left:  no change, just advance left
        if (collection[left].compareTo(collection[right]) <= 0) {
            left ++;
        } else { // Select from right:  rotate [left..right] and correct
            T tmp = collection[right]; // Will move to [left]
            rotateRight(collection, left, right - left);
            collection[left] = tmp;
            // EVERYTHING has moved up by one
            left ++; right ++; mid ++;
        }
    }       
}
```

Here is the Unit Test
    private Integer[] seed;

```
@Before
public void doBeforeEachTestCase() {
    this.seed = new Integer[]{4,2,3,1,5,8,7,6};
}
@Test
public void iterativeMergeSortFirstTest() {
    ArrayUtils.<Integer>iterativeMergeSort(seed);
    Integer[] result = new Integer[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    assertThat(seed, equalTo(result));  
}
```