# How to make color gradients in CSS with gamma correction?

Tags: css

So I just [figured out](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKnqECcg6Gw) about colors in computers being stored in logarithmic scale in order to save space.

Now I would like to apply what I've learned and create a CSS gradient with a gamma corrected color space, instead of the default, but I have not found an already existing solution on how to do it.

[image: not gamma corrected gradient]

Has anyone else worked on this before? I'm sure I could just preprogram a lot of color stops, but I wonder if there is an easier way of doing this with CSS.

Comment: https://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: @Paulie_D yes, uhm, how does this tool do gamma correction? If you try green and red you get like the "wrong" version of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39924008

Answer (score 1):

I also don't know how to do it right.
The only way I see is if you do it manually, for example I selected two colors [here](https://cssgradient.io/), then I divided the RGB code by 255 and then calculated the new code as shown in the YT video. In the end I multiplied every color with 255 to turn it back into an RGB code.
Now I have added a third transition between the other one's which I've assigned the calculated code to.
The problem of course is, that now you have the same problem that you had in the beginning, only between the new RGB-Code and the old one's. But I think it's not as noticeable to the eyes anymore and if you do the same thing one more time it could be fine.

[That's how it looks if you do the steps one time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fumaq.png) 
[and that's what it usually looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvV0T.png)