# How can I add a colour gradient feature to my bresenham line drawing algorithm?

Tags: python, c, bresenham, lerp

I've found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49321304/16498000) on StackOverflow but my python understanding isn't that good to properly translate it to C, I'm trying to add that gradient feature to this line drawing algorithm:

```
#define sign(x) ((x > 0)? 1 : ((x < 0)? -1: 0))

x = x1; 
y = y1;
dx = abs(x2 - x1); 
dy = abs(y2 - y1);
s1 = sign(x2 - x1); 
s2 = sign(y2 - y1);
swap = 0;

if (dy > dx) {
    temp = dx;
    dx = dy;
    dy = temp;
    swap = 1;
}

D = 2*dy - dx;
for (i = 0; i < dx; i++) {
    display_pixel (x, y); 
    while (D >= 0) { 
        D = D - 2*dx;
        if (swap)
            x += s1;
        else
            y += s2;
    } 
    D = D + 2*dy;
    if (swap)
        y += s2;
    else
        x += s1; 
}
```

I feel bad for asking such a trivial task but I really can't understand what is going on on the python side nor how the colours are represented (mine are int(0xttrrggbb))

Comment: Using a macro like that is a bit risky as it's not doing any type-checking. Why not use a function instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
#define GAMMA 0.43

//Returns a linear value in the range [0,1]
//for sRGB input in [0,255].
double ChannelInvCompanding(int c)
{
    double y;

    c = c & 0xFF;
    y = (double) c;
    y = y / 255.0;
    if (c <= 0.04045)
        y = y / 12.92;
    else
        y = pow(((y + 0.055) / 1.055), 2.4);
    return (y);
}

//Convert color from 0..255 to 0..1
//Inverse Srgb Companding for 
//Red, Green, and Blue
double  *InverseSrgbCompanding(int c)
{
    double  *r = malloc(4 * sizeof(double));

    r[0] = (double) get_t(c);
    r[1] = ChannelInvCompanding(get_r(c));
    r[2] = ChannelInvCompanding(get_g(c));
    r[3] = ChannelInvCompanding(get_b(c));

    return (r);
}

//Apply companding to Red, Green, and Blue
double ChannelCompanding(double c)
{
    double x;

    if (c <= 0.0031308)
        x = 12.92 * c; 
    else
        x = (1.055 * pow(c, (1/2.4))) - 0.055;
    return (x);
}

//return new color. Convert 0..1 back into 0..255
//Srgb Companding for Red, Green, and Blue
int SrgbCompanding(double *c)
{
    int t;
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;

    t = (int)c[0];
    r = (int)(ChannelCompanding(c[1]) * 255);
    g = (int)(ChannelCompanding(c[2]) * 255);
    b = (int)(ChannelCompanding(c[3]) * 255);
    free(c);
    return (create_trgb(t, r, g, b));
}

//sums channels
//does not include transperancy
double sumChannels(double *c)
{
    double x = c[1] + c[2] + c[3];
    return (x);
}

//Lerping see
//https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation
//#Programming_language_support
double lerp_int(double c1, double c2, double t)
{
    return (c1 * (1 - t) + c2 * t);
    //return ((1 - t) * c1 + t * c2);
}

double  *lerp(double *c1, double *c2, double t)
{
    double  *r = malloc(4 * sizeof(double));

    //r[1] = ((1 - t) * c1[1] + t * c2[1]);
    //r[2] = ((1 - t) * c1[2] + t * c2[2]);
    //r[3] = ((1 - t) * c1[3] + t * c2[3]);
    r[1] = (c1[1] * (1 - t)) + c2[1] * t;
    r[2] = (c1[2] * (1 - t)) + c2[2] * t;
    r[3] = (c1[3] * (1 - t)) + c2[3] * t;
    return (r);
}

typedef struct s_bresvars {
    int x; 
    int y;
    int dx; 
    int dy;
    int s1; 
    int s2;
    int swap;
    int temp;
    int d;
    int i;
}   t_bresvars;



int sign(int x)
{
    if (x > 0)
        return (1);
    else if (x < 0)
        return (-1);
    else
        return (0);
}


void    bresenhams_alg(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int scolor, int ecolor, t_vars *vars)
{
    double step;
    double *color;
    double intensity;
    double total;
    int temp;
    int d;
    int clr;

    double *color1_lin = InverseSrgbCompanding(scolor);
    double bright1 = pow(sumChannels(c.color1_lin), GAMMA);
    double *color2_lin = InverseSrgbCompanding(ecolor);
    double bright2 = pow(sumChannels(c.color2_lin), GAMMA);

    int x = x1; 
    int y = y1;
    int dx = abs(x2 - x1); 
    int dy = abs(y2 - y1);
    int s1 = sign(x2 - x1); 
    int s2 = sign(y2 - y1);
    int swap = 0;
    int i = 0;
    double step_c = 0;

    if (dy > dx) {
        temp = dx;
        dx = dy;
        dy = temp;
        swap = 1;
    }

    d = 2*dy - dx;
    step = (1.0 / dx);
    while (i < dx)
    {
        step_c += step;
        intensity = pow(lerp_int(bright1, bright2, step), (1 / GAMMA));
        color = lerp(color1_lin, color2_lin, step);
        total = sumChannels(color);
        if (total != 0)
            c[1] = (c[1] * intensity / total);
            c[2] = (c[2] * intensity / total);
            c[3] = (c[3] * intensity / total);
        clr = SrgbCompanding(color);
        pixel_put(x, y, clr); 
        while (v.d >= 0)
        { 
            v.d = v.d - 2 * v.dx;
            if (v.swap)
                v.x += v.s1;
            else
                v.y += v.s2;
        } 
        v.d = v.d + 2 * v.dy;
        if (v.swap)
            v.y += v.s2;
        else
            v.x += v.s1;
        v.i++;
    }
    free(color1_lin);
    free(color2_lin);
}
```